# Python iterating through lists and dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

This is a test project from a python book. I am trying to iterate through a list and check if each item is a key in the dictionary. If it is, then add 1 to the dictionary value, if not add the key and then set the value to 1. Here's my code so far:

```
inv_original = {'gold coin' : 42, 'rope' : 1}
dragonloot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

def addtoinventory(dict_a, addeditems):
    for i in addeditems:
        if dict_a.has_key(i):
            dict_a[str(i)] = dict_a.get(i, 0) + 1
        else:
            dict_a[str(i)] = 1
        return dict_a

    inv = addtoinventory(inv_original, dragonloot)

    print inv
```

It seems to work but only for the first item in the list, it doesn't iterate through the rest. Can anyone help please?

Comment: You're returning too early. Pro tip: [Don't use `has_key`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.has_key), simply use `if i in dict_a:`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function returns after completing the first iteration.

```
def addtoinventory(dict_a, addeditems):
    for i in addeditems:
        if dict_a.has_key(i):
            dict_a[str(i)] = dict_a.get(i, 0) + 1
        else:
            dict_a[str(i)] = 1
        return dict_a     # <----- issue here
# ...
```

You should move the `return` statement outside the loop's body by unindenting the line by 4 spaces to fix the issue. You should also consider:

- using a `try`/`except` block instead of `if`/`else`,
- removing the `str(i)` call; your list elements are already strings, so it's unnecessary to attempt a string conversion on them, and
- improved variable names (e.g. `inventory` instead of `dict_a`, and `items` instead of `addeditems`, which is likely redundant --if it's in the list, it has obviously been added :)

The updated code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

inv_original = {'gold coin' : 42, 'rope' : 1}
dragonloot   = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']

def addtoinventory(inventory, items):
    for i in items:
        try:
            inventory[i] += 1
        except KeyError:
            inventory[i] = 1

    return inventory

#
print addtoinventory(inv_original, dragonloot)
# ...
```

The code's output is now: `{'gold coin': 45, 'rope': 1, 'dagger': 1, 'ruby': 1}`, showing that the `gold coin` key has increased by `3` and other key/val pairs have been added, as you expected.